# select dropdown html page

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have two three dropdowns in webpage. Manually On selecting the first dropdown as "No" the other two automatically show zero in it. On hitting enter it moves to next html page. However I am able to select values in all the three dropdowns using vba but on hitting enter the two dropdowns again show "Select" instead of 0 and does not move to the next page.

I tried For each loop as well as getElementByID

on hitting Enter the webpages should move to another page.

```html
<select name="UnhedgedYes" id="DDLLUnhedgedYes" style="font-size: 12px;"><option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UnhedgedYes"></span>




 <select name="DDLIPRUFCE" class="DDLIPRUFCE" id="DDLIPRUFCE" style="font-size: 12px;" data-val-required="Please Select Incremental Provisioning Requirement-due to UFCE" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DDLIPRUFCE must be a number."><option value="">[Select]</option>
<option value="1" text="0">0</option><option value="6" text="10">10</option>
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="DDLIPRUFCE"></span>
 <input name="hidDDLIPRUFCE" id="hidDDLIPRUFCE" type="hidden" value="" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The hidDDLIPRUFCE field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field hidDDLIPRUFCE must be a number.">




<select name="DDLIRiskW" class="DDLIRiskW" id="DDLIRiskW" style="font-size: 12px;" data-val-required="Please Select Incremental Risk Weight- due to UFCE" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DDLIRiskW must be a number."><option value="">[Select]</option>
<option value="2" text="0">0</option><option value="1" text="25">25</option></select>
                                            
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="DDLIRiskW"></span>
 <input name="hidDDLIRiskW" id="hidDDLIRiskW" type="hidden" value="" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The hidDDLIRiskW field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field hidDDLIRiskW must be a number.">
```

Below are the codes I tried but these does not work.

1

```
ie.document.querySelector("option[value=No]").Selected = True
```

2

```
Set oSelect = ie.document.getElementById("DDLLUnhedgedYes")
oSelect.selectedIndex = 1
oSelect.FireEvent "onchange" ' although there is no fireevent exist on this element.
```

3

```
For Each op In ie.document.querySelectorAll("option")
    If op.innerText = 0 Then
        op.Selected = True
        t = t + 1
        If t = 2 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

4 This code will enter No in the first dropdown and 0 in other two, will disable the other two dropdown. But on hitting enter remains on the same page 
    instead shows [Select] in other two dropdowns

```
Set Post = ie.document.getElementById("DDLLUnhedgedYes")
''I didn't use any index to do the job

For Each elem In Post.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If InStr(elem.Value, "No") > 0 Then
         elem.Selected = True
         ie.document.getElementById("DDLIPRUFCE").getElementsByTagName("option")(1).Selected = True: ie.document.getElementById("DDLIPRUFCE").FireEvent ("onchange")
         ie.document.getElementById("DDLIPRUFCE").disabled = True
         ie.document.getElementById("DDLIRiskW").getElementsByTagName("option")(1).Selected = True: ie.document.getElementById("DDLIRiskW").FireEvent ("onchange")
        ie.document.getElementById("DDLIRiskW").disabled = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next elem

ie.document.getElementById("btnEnter").Click
```

Comment: This a private url?